# Is there any way to access r_fullprofile permission in LinkedIn iOS integration?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

My application is currently using it for fetching the users "Birthdate" , "Contact no" which requires r_fullprofile instead of r_basicprofile.

Would I need to do any changes regarding the new policy if I only used r_basicprofile?

Answer (score 2):

For full profile permission, you must be a LinkedIn Partner.

Partner Program Application Form: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

2 or 3 weeks after making the application will return the answer.

Comment: This LinkedIn Partner Program is free or any cost ?